# vmstat - Threads Waiting for Runtime vs Load Average?

Tags: vmstat

I've read in a few places now that "load average" shown in `top`, `uptime`, and other places is based on the *"average length of run queue"*.

I'm looking at the first column in `vmstat` with the header `r1` which is described as *"threads waiting for runtime"*.

I just want to confirm that these 2 stats are essentially the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same:

- vmstat reports instant state
- load_average are 1,5,15 mintues averages

Comment: But the first line of `vmstat` is always the average since startup. I'm asking if it's the same metric but on a different time length for the first line.

Comment: Yes apparently it's the same metric. Processes running or waiting for execution.